# Load an array from an external txt

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I store an array using a txt file, how can I load it back to jQuery?

Assuming the external txt is

```
['Parrot', 'Green'], ['Crow', 'Black'], ['Duck', 'White']
```

How can I load it as

```
var myArr = [ ['Parrot', 'Green'], ['Crow', 'Black'], ['Duck', 'White'] ];
```

This is what I've been trying. Does not work.

```
var myArr;
$.ajax({url: 'files/external.txt'}).done(function(d) {
    myArr = JSON.parse('[' + d + ']');
});
```

Comment: The content of your file doesn't conform to JSON format: there should be double-quotes instead of single-quotes. So you cannot use `JSON.parse`.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have associative array and it sucks ... so use json( ___Valid JSON___ )   like other users are saying

Comment: Did you want this => `var txt = "['Parrot', 'Green'], ['Crow', 'Black'], ['Duck', 'White']", myArr = []; myArr.push(txt);alert (myArr);`

Comment: If you are willing to, and able to, change the entire format of the `.txt`, why not just save the content as a `.js` holding a real array you can include? :)

Comment: @davidkonrad: good suggestion. thanks. I've got it all sorted and works fine now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trying to parse 'external' as JSON, but the content does not adhere to the JSON-specification.

Try wrapping all text inside double-quotes instead of single-quotes.

```
 //external.json
 [
    [
        "Parrot",
        "Green"
    ],
    [
        "Crow",
        "Black"
    ],
    [
        "Duck",
        "White"
    ]
]
```

Your code could then look like

```
$.ajax({url: 'files/external.json'}).done(function(d) {
myArr = JSON.parse(d);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to change quote and do following -

```
var strArr = '[["Parrot", "Green"], ["Crow", "Black"], ["Duck", "White"]]';

var finalArr = JSON.parse(strArr);
```